# WinUI 3 ListView Linked To Observablecollection contains Canvases

Tags: listview, canvas, datatemplate, winui-3, winui

I am developing a WinUI 3 application which contains a ListView linked to an Observablecollection which contains canvases , the listview displays the names of the canvases via a DataTemplate but the names are not displayed

```xml
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
    <ListView x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="listViewCanvases" Background="SeaGreen" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Canvas.Name}" />
                 </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

```cs
ObservableCollection<Canvas> ocCanvases = new ObservableCollection<Canvas>();
                         
ocCanvases.Add(new Canvas(){Name="AAA"});
             
ocCanvases.Add(new Canvas() { Name = "BBB" });
          
ocCanvases.Add(new Canvas() { Name = "CCC" });
          
listViewCanvases.ItemsSource = ocCanvases;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```xml
<StackPanel
    Grid.Row="1"
    Orientation="Vertical">
    <ListView
        x:Name="listViewCanvases"
        x:FieldModifier="public"
        Background="SeaGreen">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="Canvas">
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Name, Mode=OneWay}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```

Comment: Yes, it works but as @mm8 mentioned, you should consider using ``DataTemplate`` for this.

Comment: I want to create an application like photoshop main canvas which groups layer canvases, a listview which displays the name of the layers and a visibility button via a datatemplate I created the class layer derived from the class convas

public class Layer : Canvas
{
     public string Name { get; set; }
     public bool IsVisible { get; set; }
      publicLayer()
     {
         Name = "New Layer";
         IsVisible = true;
     } }

with  <DataTemplatex:DataType="Canvas">
  his work
but with Layer does not work
  <DataTemplatex:DataType="Layer">   @mm8

Answer (score 0):

You should not add `UIElement` derived types like `Canvas` to source collections.

Add data objects (or plain strings in this case) instead and then create the `Canvas` elements in the `DataTemplate` in the view:

```
ObservableCollection<string> oc = new ObservableCollection<string>();
oc.Add("AAA");
oc.Add("BBB");
oc.Add("CCC");
listViewCanvases.ItemsSource = oc;
```

**XAML:**

```
<StackPanel Grid.Row="1" Orientation="Vertical">
    <ListView x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="listViewCanvases" Background="SeaGreen" >
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate x:DataType="x:String">
                <StackPanel>
                    <Canvas>
                        <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind Mode=OneWay}" />
                    </Canvas>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</StackPanel>
```